# Label plot based on condition

Tags: r, plot, label, dot

I have a dot plot with data from dataframe `df_roles$result` and would like to assign labels only to certain dots specified by their specific name in `df_roles$name`.

[image]

My expected output is to have e.g. China labelled.

I have tried both these arguments but they won't work:

```
ifelse(df_roles$name = "China", 
text(df_roles[[3]], df_roles[[2]], labels = df_roles[[1]], pos = 2, cex=0.3), " ")

geom_text(data = filter(df_roles$result, df_roles$name=="China"),aes(label=df_roles$name))
```

Reproducible example:

```
df_roles <- structure(list(name = structure(1:6, .Label = c("Afghanistan", 
"Albania", "Algeria", "Angola", "Argentina", "Armenia", "Australia", 
"Austria", "Azerbaijan", "Bahrain", "Bangladesh", "Barbados", 
"Belarus", "Belgium", "Belize", "Benin", "Bolivia", "Bosnia and Herzegovina", 
"Botswana", "Brazil", "Bulgaria", "Burkina Faso", "Burundi", 
"Cameroon", "Canada", "Chile", "China", "Colombia", "Congo", 
"Costa Rica", "Croatia", "Cuba", "Cyprus", "Democratic Republic of the Congo", 
"Denmark", "Dominican Republic", "Ecuador", "Egypt", "El Salvador", 
"Eritrea", "Estonia", "Ethiopia", "Finland", "France", "Gabon", 
"Gambia", "Georgia", "Germany", "Ghana", "Greece", "Grenada", 
"Guatemala", "Guinea", "Guyana", "Haiti", "Honduras", "Hungary", 
"India", "Indonesia", "Iran ", "Iraq", "Ireland", "Israel", "Italy", 
"Jamaica", "Japan", "Jordan", "Kazakhstan", "Kenya", "Kuwait", 
"Kyrgyzstan", "Latvia", "Lebanon", "Lesotho", "Liberia", "Libya", 
"Lithuania", "Luxembourg", "Malawi", "Malaysia", "Mali", "Malta", 
"Mauritania", "Mexico", "Mongolia", "Montenegro", "Morocco", 
"Mozambique", "Namibia", "Nepal", "Netherlands", "New Zealand", 
"Nicaragua", "Nigeria", "Norway", "Oman", "Pakistan", "Palestine", 
"Panama", "Paraguay", "Peru", "Philippines", "Poland", "Portugal", 
"Qatar", "Republic of Korea", "Republic of Moldova", "Romania", 
"Russia", "Rwanda", "Saint Lucia", "Saint Vincent and the Grenadines", 
"Saudi Arabia", "Senegal", "Serbia", "Singapore", "Slovakia", 
"Slovenia", "Somalia", "South Africa", "Spain", "Sri Lanka", 
"Sudan", "Suriname", "Sweden", "Switzerland", "Syria", "Taiwan", 
"Tajikistan", "Thailand", "Togo", "Trinidad and Tobago", "Tunisia", 
"Turkey", "Turkmenistan", "Uganda", "UK", "Ukraine", "United Arab Emirates", 
"United Republic of Tanzania", "United States of America", "Uruguay", 
"Uzbekistan", "Venezuela", "Viet Nam", "Yemen", "Zambia", "Zimbabwe"
), class = "factor"), result = c(0.0900102874778869, -0.0934265332577318, 
-0.177974826946747, -0.590024694573266, 1.20884852383168, -0.183452483887309
)), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Conditional labeling in ggplot2 using geom\_text and subsetting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36556087/conditional-labeling-in-ggplot2-using-geom-text-and-subsetting)

Comment: @RonakShah Now added

Comment: @user438383 I don't think so, or at least I'm not sure how to implement it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the data shared does not have `'China'` in it I am using `'Afghanistan'` as an example. Also using row number as x-axis.

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

df_roles %>%
  mutate(name = as.character(name), 
         label = replace(name, name != 'Afghanistan', ''), 
         row = row_number()) %>%
  ggplot(aes(row, result, label = label)) + 
  geom_point() + geom_text(vjust = -0.5)
```

[image]

Comment: This worked, thanks Ronak!